# How to append a bootstrap element with JavaScript to a HTML document already created?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I want to insert an alert from bootstrap with JavaScript code into a HTML already created

I've tried the following code:

```
<script>
let field= document.getElementById("someID");
let text = document.write("
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times; 
    </button><strong>Danger!</strong> This alert box could indicate a 
    dangerous or potentially negative action.
    </div>
   ");
  paragraph.appendChild(field);
</script>
```

but for some reason this did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add some html to `field` try

```
field.innerHTML += '<div ... your html ...'
```

Comment: that's did not works because the keyword "class" javascritp take it literally and some other words as "alert"

Comment: if you want to use multiline html use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (shift+tilde)

Comment: @shaveax don't forget to click on big gray check button on left side of this answer to accept it

Comment: i can't, when i try to do it i have the following message: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @shaveax try now